# How to fire/invoke event when checked status is altered with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to fire the change event when other JavaScript function changes the checked status.
Simplified code below. I can not call `MyFunc()` from `MyOtherFunc()`.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:radio[name=rdName]').change(function(){
    MyFunc();
  });
});
function MyFunc(){
  //do stuff
}
function MyOtherFunc(){
  $('input:radio[name=rdName]')[0].checked = true;
  // Was unable to have it change based on a value
}
```

Radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdName" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="rdName" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="rdName" value="3">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('input:radio[name=rdName]').change();
```

Comment: +1 Deleted my answer after rereading the question, and realizing it was specifically about firing an event.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:radio[name=rdName]').change(function(){
    MyFunc();
  });
});
function MyFunc(){
  //do stuff
}
function MyOtherFunc(){
  $('input:radio[name=rdName]').attr('checked', 'checked').trigger('change');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:radio[name=rdName]').bind('customChange',function(){
    MyFunc();
  });
});
function MyFunc(){
  alert("it's work")
}
function MyOtherFunc(){
  $('input:radio[name=rdName]')[0].checked = true;
  $('input:radio[name=rdName]').trigger('customChange');
}
```

If you have some problems with scope you can use  [.trigger( eventType, extraParameters )](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)